# Can't get my overlay login form to close

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery to create an overlay that shows up when a user clicks on a 'log in' list item in my navigation. 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akAQ9/)

So far everything works. The only issue is trying to get it to close. I cannot get the overlay box to go away.

When I look in my console, I get - "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" Line 111

Line 111 is where my close function begins. Im not sure what I did wrong. Here is the code for line 111

```
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function () {
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Here is the full Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.login-window').click(function () {

        // Getting the variable's value from a link
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2;

        $(loginBox).css({
            'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function () {
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
        <a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
        <form action="https://www.theiracenter.com/customerLoginAction.gsx" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input class="topLogin" type="text" name="login" width="125px" />
            <br />
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input class="topLogin" id="passwordText" type="password" name="password" width="125px" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pd" value="C05" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
/* Mask for background, by default is not display */
#mask {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 999;
}

/* You can customize to your needs  */
.login-popup {
    display: none;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* CSS3 */
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* Firefox */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
    /* Safari, Chrome */
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    /* Firefox */
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    /* Safari, Chrome */;
}

img.btn_close {
    Position the close button
    float: right;
    margin: -28px -28px 0 0;
}

fieldset {
    border: none;
}

form.signin .textbox label {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

form.signin .textbox span {
    display: block;
}

form.signin p, form.signin span {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

form.signin .textbox input {
    background: #666666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 6px 4px;
    width: 200px;
}

form.signin input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #bbb;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
}

form.signin input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #bbb;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
}

.button {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f3f3f3), to(#dddddd));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#f3f3f3', EndColorStr='#dddddd');
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 6px 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font: 12px;
    width: 214px;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. and you're using 1.8+!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated since jQuery 1.7. and you're using 1.8+! You should use `.on()`

```
$(document.body).on('click','a.close, #mask', function () {
      $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
          $('#mask').remove();
      });
     return false;
});
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akAQ9/5/)

Comment: changing it to .on worked for me! Thanks! Will accept as answer

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, clicking on the mask doesn't work - it should close it

Answer (score 1):

live has been deprecated from 1.7 and removed from 1.9 try using `.on` instead like so:

```
// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('body').on('click', 'a.close, #mask', function () {
    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#mask').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/akAQ9/2/)

By binding it this way your mask will always close the popup (as you create and append the mask in the onclick - if you bind the click directly to the mask, then you will need to rebind  everytime you create the mask